# variable expansion problem

Tags: bash, lubuntu, locale

I'm running lubuntu 20.04  bare installation no docker involved.

```
env | grep -i shell
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

whenever I try to let expand system variablen like $HOME auto complete is not working correct. Example $HOME

```
echo $HOME
/home/alex
```

correct set.

```
     cat \$HOME/zu_entfernende_Kernel 
cat: '$HOME/zu_entfernende_Kernel': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

when I hit tab for autocomplete,`$HOME` is expand to `\$HOME` sorry for german output, but the error seems to have something to do with my locale.

Note when I use

```
LANG=C
```

before it is working as expected.

```
alex@Guilmon:~$ LANG=C
alex@Guilmon:~$ cat $HOME/zu_entfernende_Kernel
linux-headers-5.3.0-62
linux-headers-5.3.0-62-generic
linux-image-5.3.0-62-generic
alex@Guilmon:~$
```

locale Information

```
    localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: de
      X11 Layout: de
       X11 Model: pc105
     X11 Options: caps:none
```

any idea how I can pin the error down?

Comment: `shopt -s direxpand`, you may want to add it to `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Hm but why it is working when I change LANG before? But I will try the answers thank you.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your problem but the *LANG=C* example, even if it's desirable, is the one not working.

Comment: Somehow autocomplete isn't able to resolve the path in that example.

Answer (score 0):

easy solution in my case erase $HOME/.bashrc.

From the original file in /etc/skel/.bashrc

```
if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

Means read this file if it is present.
and  here is this for me bothering feature.

```
# Turn on extended globbing and programmable completion
shopt -s extglob progcomp
```